# JavaScript Double Null Check and Locking

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous, locking

In a language with threads and locks it is easy to implement a lazy load by checking the value of a variable, if it's null then lock the next section of code, check the value again and then load the resource and assign. This prevents it from being loaded multiple times and causes threads after the first to wait for the first thread to complete the action that's needed.

Psuedo code:

```
  if(myvar == null) {
    lock(obj) {
      if(myvar == null) {
        myvar = getData();
      }
    }
  }
  return myvar;
```

JavaScript runs in a single thread, however, it still has this type of issue because of asynchronous execution while one call is waiting on a blocking resource. In this Node.js example:

```
var allRecords;
module.exports = getAllRecords(callback) {
  if(allRecords) {
    return callback(null,allRecords);
  }

  db.getRecords({}, function(err, records) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    }

    // Use existing object if it has been
    // set by another async request to this
    // function
    allRecords = allRecords || partners;

    return callback(null, allRecords);
  });
}
```

I'm lazy loading all the records from a small DB table the first time this function is called and then returning the in-memory records on subsequent calls.

Problem: If multiple async requests are made to this function at the same time then the table is going to be loaded unnecessarily from the DB multiple times.

In order to solve this I could simulate a locking mechanism by creating a `var lock;` variable and setting it to true while the table is loading. I would then put the other async calls into a `setTimeout()` loop and check back on this variable every (say) 1 second until the data was available and then allow them to return.

The problems with that solution are:

1. It's fragile, what if the first async call throws and doesn't unset the lock.
2. How many times do we loop back into the timer before giving up?
3. How long should the timer be set for? In some environments 1 second might be way too long and inefficient.

Is there a best practise for solving this in JavaScript?

Comment: I would use promises. On the first invocation of this function, create a promise and return it. On subsequent invocations, return that same promise. Resolve it when data is available.

Comment: @KevinB if you re-used the same promise instance, how would the separate callbacks be kept straight?  I guess the promise library would just handle multiple `.then()` invocations and do the right thing? (I've not written a whole lot of Promise-based code, at least not much beyond super-simple stuff.)

Comment: It depends on implementation ( i also haven't done much beyond super-simple stuff with promises ) however i'm pretty sure .then() returns a new promise if anything was returned from the passed in callback, meaning using .then multiple times on this promise shouldn't affect it's outcome unless you override it with `thepromise = thepromise.then(...`

Answer (score 2):

On the first call to the service, initialize an array. Start the fetch operation. Create a Promise, store it in the array.

On subsequent calls, if the data is there, return an already-fulfilled Promise. If not, add another Promise to the array and return that.

When the data arrives, resolve all the waiting Promise objects in the list. (You can throw away the list once the data's there.)

Answer (score 1):

I really like the promise solution in the other answer -- very clever, very interesting.  Promises aren't the dominent methodology, so you may need to educate the team.  I'm going to go in another direction though.

What you're after is a memoize function -- an in-memory key/value cache of expensive results.  JavaScript the Good Parts has a [memoize](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javascript-the-good/9780596517748/ch04s15.html) sample towards the end.  Lodash has a [memoize](https://lodash.com/docs#memoize) function.  These assume synchronous processing so don't account for your scenario -- which is to say they'd hit the database lots of times until one of the "threads" replied.

The async library also has a [memoize](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/async.js#L994) function that does exactly what you want.  In it's innards, it keeps a queue array of callbacks, and once it gets the answer, it both caches it and calls all the callbacks.

If you're into inventing, by all means, use promises.  If you'd just like a plug-n-play answer, use async#memoize.